# Adyen plugin installation into SAP Hybris (sample repository)

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud, adyen

I have completed a setup and build for SAP Commerce Cloud using their '[SAP Commerce Cloud Sample Repository](https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-commerce-sample-setup/tree/main)' as per [these](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/1be46286b36a4aa48205be5a96240672/76450bc02bdf492689ca5e6d35c670e6.html?locale=en-US) instructions.

I am now trying to install the [Adyen SAP Commerce (Hybris) v6 plugin](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-hybris#1-copy-extension-files-to-bincustom-directory).

I have been able to follow the instructions in the README up to step 4 - the 'Build' stage - where it states to change to the `bin/platform` directory, and execute the `setantenv.sh` script
([github build stage instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3a3.png))

The sample repository provided by SAP, however, does not have any such `bin/platform` directory, nor does the `setantenv.sh` script exist anywhere within the repository. So, I'm not sure how to proceed...

Another set of instructions on the Adyen docs website, adds the *qualifying* instruction for this step as "Install the Adyen add-on into your existing storefront template:"
([adyen docs build stage instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYE7v.png))

This is only somewhat helpful, however, as I don't know if I even have an "..existing storefront template". In my SAP commerce environment, I have links to both a 'JS Storefront', and a 'Storefront', however, whilst the endpoint for the 'JS Storefront' takes me to a sample store, the endpoint for 'Storefront' simply returns a 404.

I'm hoping that someone might be able to provide some direction here. Is it even possible to install the Adyen plugin with my current configuration (i.e. when using the SAP Commerce Cloud Sample Repository in its vanilla form)? Is it maybe possible, but I have to install a Storefront first (and if so, how would I go about this?) Can this be done with the 'JS Storefront'?

I have not 'tried' anything, as the `bin/platform` directory doesn't exist, so I'm simply not sure how to proceed...

---

*For context, I work in the DevOps space, and am trying to set this up for our development team, but have limited (pretty much none) experience with commerce platforms.*

Comment: The sample repository by SAP is something to install on top of the SAP Commerce Cloud zip. It's an example how you need to structure your repository to deploy to the cloud environment. You need to download SAP Commerce Cloud from the market place https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/8be4e0379b294fbabf36d26e7ca4169d/9f99b61bd8f14414a60340ee5d77a51f.html?locale=en-US